# Choosing a dev board for physics simulation

Tags: microcontroller

I am looking for a development board (microcontroller based), with reasonably powerful math functionality, for real-time simiulation of oscillation systems (pendulums,SHM,shock absorbers etc.) and other similar systems which can be modelled using differential equations. I hope to represent the solutions graphically on an ossiloscope, so the board should also have analog output with sufficient resolution.
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Do you need floating point math, or can you make do with fixed point algorithms?  The former will be significantly more expensive and hard to find than the latter.

Comment: Please provide some more information about your project. Why do you need a board and not just a PC? Will the board measure anything or only simulate and drive the scope?

Comment: I know that it could be done much more easily on a PC (and I have done something similar on the PC), but I want to build a standalone device for the purpose(to create something similar to an analog computer, but implemented digitally). I do need floating point functionality.It wouldn't have to measure any inputs from sensors, the only inputs I need are just to toggle between types of and changing several parameters(so several push buttons and one or two potentiometers.

Comment: @reemrevnivek I was hoping to use the RK method to solve the ODEs and I don't know of any algorithms for integration that only uses integers that can be run in realtime.

Answer (score 2):

It would make more sense to do your simulation on a PC using MATLAB (expensive) or Scilab (free). Output can be plotted graphically, you won't need a scope.

Comment: my friends doing computer vision and other heavily simulation based work often find that controlling a graphics card and using it can be 5 or more orders of magnitude faster then matlab. This can mean the difference between days and seconds.

Comment: The simulation that Alexdagre8 wants to do is much less demanding than that, MATLAB and Scilab on a PC should be quite adequate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a smartphone/PDA.

Most have serial ports for IO, and you could probably get analog output through the headphone output, if you don't mind a ~20hz highpass filter.

Alternatively, the [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) is a chunky SOC dev-board, with floating point capabilities, and has parallel IO, so you should be able to attach a DAC to it.

Comment: I plan on giving it to my school as a present so I want to keep the budget to a minimum, so are there cheaper dev boards than a beagleboard(suitable for this purpose)? If not would an old 1G iPod touch work.